# Google app script to have cell validate from a list without showing suggestions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a range of values I want to set up Google App Script to validate, but, for privacy reasons, I do not want the user to be able to see the suggestions as they type. I also want to allow them to use invalid values, but to have the red icon in the upper-left corner of the cell to show up when the value is invalid.

This is my code:

```
var clientColumnValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(dropdownClients, false).setAllowInvalid(true).build();
```

I've tried [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requirevalueinlistvalues,-showdropdown) in my code, setting 'show dropdown' to false, but it just gets rid of the dropdown, it doesn't hide the suggestions as I type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DataValidationBuilder.requireFormulaSatisfied()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requireformulasatisfiedformula), like this:

```js
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A2:A');
  const topLeftCellA1 = range.offset(0, 0, 1, 1).getA1Notation();
  const clients = ['ACME', 'Contoso', 'NewCo', 'Northwind', 'Oceanic Airlines'];
  const _escapeRegExCharacters = (s) => s.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
  const clientsRegex = clients.map(_escapeRegExCharacters).join('|');
  const formula = `=regexmatch(${topLeftCellA1}, "(?i)^(${clientsRegex})$")`;
  const rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
    .requireFormulaSatisfied(formula)
    .setAllowInvalid(true)
    .build();
  range.setDataValidation(rule);
```

You can get the list of client names from a spreadsheet range instead of hardcoding them.

Comment: Thank you. For mine, I had to **toString()** to the fourth line and this worked: ```const _escapeRegExCharacters = (s) => s.toString().replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');```